# Variable assignment in function doesn't return it after the function is called

Tags: python, function, variable-assignment

I have a function get_arcs():

```
for i in rng:
    if not lines[i].startswith('[') and 'echo $ORACLE_SID' in lines[i].strip():
            sid = lines[i + 2]
            yield sid
    if lines[i].strip().find('SELECT') == 0:
        res = lines[i:]
        for i in res:
            print >> f, i.strip()
            yield i.strip()
```

which supposed to:

1. assign a certain value to variable sid
2. write different content to f-file
3. have the generator of **i.strip()** as the output which will be passed the to another function and the sum of certain objects will be calculated

The problem is when the get_arcs() is called:

```
for line in get_arcs():
    if len(line.split()) == 13:
        lst.append(int(line.split()[-5]))
print sum(lst), 'Bytes'
```

It does return the sum(lst) as expected, but how can I retrieve my **sid** value, as I cannot call it anywhere outside of the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you need this function to return both `i.strip()` and `sid`? I always find it a code smell when you try to return two values from a single function. But if it really is necessary in this case, I would return a tuple.

```
yield i.strip(), sid
```

Later:

```
for (line, sid) in get_arcs():
    # both line and sid are defined here
```

Comment: Yes, this worked just fine. Thanks a lot!   P.S. yes I do need 1 func to return two values, since there is a paramiko ssh connection gets established as well.

Comment: Of course, there's an exception to every rule. It's just always worth double checking in these cases. ;)